# Javascript restrictions on accessing remote servlet

Tags: javascript, servlets

I have the following setup:

Host `C` is the client that runs a browser.

Host `S1` is a server that hosts our html files.

Host `S2` is a server that hosts our Java servlets.

I would like my javascript code to be loaded from either an HTML file on `C` or on `S1` and then submit a form to (plus get response from) server `S2`.

NOTE: on loading from `C`, the HTML file is to be opened directly without needing a web server.

It seems that Javascript restrictions do not allow this to happen, but I am not able to find proper documentation of these restrictions anywhere. Keeping in mind that I am very new to javascript (my 1st day today), please point me to the right answer/resources.

Right now the computers are named as follows:

`S1 = server1.subdomain1.mydomain.com`

`S2 = server2.subdomain2.mydomain.com`

`C = client.subdomain3.mydomain.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perhaps due to the "Cross domain restriction" : see example at  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy (in the table)

```
http://www.example.com/dir/maint.html
http://v2.www.example.com/dir/other.html    Failure Different host (exact match required)
```

Right ?

AKA.

Answer (score 1):

Read this page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. This policy "prevents access to most methods and properties across pages on different sites".

There are workarounds for bypassing this same origin policy, by using JSONP or iframes.